# unable to select values containing " - " from excel using c# query

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to load data from an Excel sheet.  When I am select data from an Excel sheet, then I get some blank cells which originally contain a `-` in the values. For example, if a cell contains `91203327-12` then i am getting this blank after fetching data in c#.

In Excel sheet ...

[image]

... after fetching the data with ...

```
objcmd.Connection = objconexcel;
objcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
dAdapter.SelectCommand = objcmd;
dAdapter.Fill(dtresult);
```

... I'm getting this:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is an Excel issue and not a data table issue?  Is your datatable strongly typed such that `Maconomy` is an `int` or some other numeric type?

Comment: ya sure Excel issue my datatable column is string type

Comment: Excel doesn't have types. The OLEDB provider tries to guess the type by reading the first X rows (registry setting, 8 by default). If it guesses incorrectly, invalid values will be ignored. What is your connection string? Did you add `IMEX=1` in the Extended properties? This setting instructs the provider to load everything as text

Comment: I was using IMEX=2 and also tried with IMEX=1 but still i am facing the problem